# Simulate a car overtaking another one with opengl

Tags: c++, animation

I want to simulate 2 cars running on the street, with opengl. For this I chose to represent each car as a rectangle (blue - the slow car, red - the car overtaking the other).

I have the following code:

**main function**

```
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("cars");
    glewInit();
    Initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);
    glutIdleFunc(idle); 
    glutCloseFunc(Cleanup);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

**idle function**

```
float x1 = -1., x2 = -2., yy = 0.; 
//x1 is the x coordinate of the slow car, x2 and yy for the overtaking car
void idle()
{
    if (x1 <= 2) //stil in the window, slowly moving the rectangle
    {
        x1 += 0.0001;
        if (x1 < -0.25 && x1 > 0.25)
            yy = 0;
        //here i wanted the overtaking to take place, when the x of the slow car is in [-0.25; 0.25]
        else if (x1 > -0.25 && x1 < 0.25) 
            yy = 0.5; // i make the 2nd car go up
    }
    else //go back to window
        x1 = -1.5;

    if (x2 <= 2)
        x2 += 0.0004;
    else
        x2 = -1.5;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

**display/ render function**

```
void RenderFunction(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // slow rectangle
    {
        myMatrix = glm::mat4(1.f); // identity matrix 4x4
        matrTransl1 = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(x1, 0.0f, 0.0f)); //translate along x1
        myMatrix = matrTransl1 * glm::mat4(1.f);
        myMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramId, "myMatrix");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(myMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &myMatrix[0][0]);
        codCol = 0;
        codColLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramId, "codCol");
        glUniform1i(codColLocation, codCol);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
    }
    
    // "faster" rectangle
    {
        matrTransl1 = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(x2, yy, 0.0f));
        myMatrix = matrTransl1 * glm::mat4(1.f);
        myMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramId, "myMatrix");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(myMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &myMatrix[0][0]);
        codCol = 1;
        codColLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramId, "codCol");
        glUniform1i(codColLocation, codCol);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
    }
glFlush();
}
```

My main problem is that I don't really understand when/ how the red rectangle is going up and once it goes up it never goes down.. Any tips into what I should look?

Answer (score 2):

This is because your condition is wrong: `if (x1 < -0.25 && x1 > 0.25)` is a logically false statement.  It can never evaluate to true.

You *could* replace your `&&` with `||` here, but doing that would create a gap in your logic for values of `x1` that are exactly -0.25 or 0.25.  Because neither statement handles this, but might give the appearance of doing so, that approach could cause a bug for you one day.

Not to mention, doing this also duplicates constants and makes the code harder to read and maintain.

Either of the following would be fine:

```
if (x1 > -0.25 && x1 < 0.25) 
    yy = 0.5;
else
    yy = 0.0;
```

Or:

```
yy = 0.0;
if (x1 > -0.25 && x1 < 0.25) 
    yy = 0.5;
```

Comment: thank you a lot! it has a closer behaviour to what i wanted to do. could you also give me a tip on how to make the overtaking "real" ? my guess is that i have to find out when i have to change the yy value, not when x1 is in [-0.25; 0.25] but maybe when x1 is greater/ smaller than x2 ?

Comment: Try to avoid asking new questions as comments on the answer to your original question.  Just to indulge you for a moment, you need to choose the interval over which the car should move from one location to the next.  Right now, your car moves very quickly in one moment of time.  Instead, think about "how long does my passing maneuver take?" and go from there.  You may want to make the change with step-wise calculations, or you might even choose to express the movement as a mathematical function of `x1` over that range (e.g. quadratic interpolation).  Best is to try stuff and see what happens.

Comment: will keep it in mind!